# How to use money gem with form builder properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, currency

I have model Product with fields price_cents and price_currency. Money default currency is USD.

Model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  CURRENCIES = %w(USD EUR)

  composed_of :price,
              :class_name => "Money",
              :mapping => [%w(price_cents cents), %w(price_currency currency_as_string)],
              :constructor => Proc.new { |cents, currency| Money.new(cents || 0, currency || Money.default_currency) },
              :converter => Proc.new { |value| value.respond_to?(:to_money) ? value.to_money : raise(ArgumentError, "Can't convert #{value.class} to Money") }
end
```

Form:

```
= form_for @product do |f|
  = f.label :price
  = f.text_field :price
  = f.select :price_currency, Product::CURRENCIES

  = f.submit
```

Controller Create method: @product = Product.new(params[:product])

Problem: When user sets price field to 100 for example and price_currency to EUR it creates price using default currency(USD). How I can fix it? Is it possible to do it in view or i should do it in controller (e.g. @product.price.currency = ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. [Setting currency with form select with Money gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988882/setting-currency-with-form-select-with-money-gem)

Solved it by adding one line in the create method. Check the thread above, and let me know i you need further help on this one.